# Dynamically assign reference of a control

Tags: vb.net, reference, controls

I have a desktop application where I have many textboxes inside a tab control and four tabs, as each of the tabs is exact copy.

Currently I'm assigning line by line controls to corresponding control array so I can easily access control of active tab. Each tab represents a shopping basket. And I have four tabs for now. lvBasket1 is on the fist tab, lvBasket2 is on the second etc...

Part of my code:

```
Private Sub InitControlsArrayAndEventHandlers()
    lvBasket(0) = lvBasket1
    lvBasket(1) = lvBasket2
    lvBasket(2) = lvBasket3
    lvBasket(3) = lvBasket4

    btnSave(0) = btnSave1
    btnSave(1) = btnSave2
    btnSave(2) = btnSave3
    btnSave(3) = btnSave4

    For i As Integer = 0 To 3
        AddHandler lvBasket(i).MouseDoubleClick, AddressOf lvBasket_MouseDoubleClick
        AddHandler btnSave(i).Click, AddressOf btnSave_Click
    Next
End Sub
```

Question is; Is it possible somehow to assign control reference to its array, inside the for loop. Like eval in javascript:

```
lvBasket(i) = Eval("lvBasket" & i)
btnSave(i) = Eval("btnSave" & i)
```

Comment: `Like eval in javascript` (edit) No.  VB and C# are more strongly typed so you need an actual reference. the closest thing would be `tabPage.Controls("lvBasket" & i.ToString())` which would return `Control`   (or Nothing) which then needs to be cast to that Type in order to use the specific type properties.

Comment: I've tried lvBasket(i) = Me.Controls("lvBasket" & (i + 1)) but the application just ends without any error...

Comment: Thats because they are not in the form (`Me`) controls collection (if they are on Tabs).  The answer (and comment) shows getting them from the tabpage controls collection.  You dont need to assign them one by one.

Comment: I forgot to mention, but lvBasket1 is at first tab, lvBasket2 at second etc...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you already have 3 references to the controls:

1. The one in the controls collection
2. the one in the array
3. Possibly the `lvBasketN` variables shown

Since it is pretty easy to get a control from the controls collection, you really do not need a separate collection of them.  To hook up a set of newly added controls to event handlers (given the name, I am assuming `Listviews`):

```
For Each lv As ListView In TabPage8.Controls.OfType(Of ListView)()
    AddHandler lv.MouseDoubleClick, AddressOf lv_MouseDoubleClick
Next
```

---

`And I have four tabs for now. lvBasket1 is on the fist tab, lvBasket2 is on the second etc...` [an edit not in the original post]

To keep track of controls scattered across *different* controls collections, use a `List(of T)` and just add them when they are created.  If you hook up event handlers as part of creating the control, you dont need a loop at all.

```
Private baskets As New List(of Listview)
...

Dim lv As New ListView  ' e.g lvbasjket1
lv.Name = "ziggy"
... many props
AddHandler lv.MouseDoubleClick, AddressOf lvBasket_MouseDoubleClick
baskets.Add(lv)                    ' add to secondary collection
BasketTab1.Controls.Add(lv)        ' add to controls collection

lv = New ListView       ' ie lvBasket2
...
baskets.Add(lv)
BasketTab2.Controls.Add(lv)
```

The handlers were added as the control was created, so there is no *need* for any loop, though you could create them in a loop and add them to the list.

Lists are easier to work with than arrays, but `baskets(0)` will refer to the first one created, `baskets(1)` to the second etc.  You can do the same thing for buttons, textboxes etc, but these are all still grouped together in each TabPage's  control collection making it easy to get them without creating additional references:

```
' do something to basket one on tabpage 1
Dim n = 1
Dim lv = TabControl2.TabPages(n - 1).Controls().OfType(Of ListView)().FirstOrDefault()

If lv IsNot Nothing Then
    ' do something wonderful
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `Me.Controls.Find` as follows:

```
Option Strict On

Public Class Form1

  Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Call InitControlsArrayAndEventHandlers()
  End Sub
  Private lvBasket(-1) As ListView
  Private btnSave(-1) As Button


  Private Sub InitControlsArrayAndEventHandlers()
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Do
      Dim ctl() As Control = Me.Controls.Find("lvBasket" & i.ToString, True)
      If ctl.GetUpperBound(0) = -1 Then Exit Do 'finished      
      ReDim Preserve lvBasket(i - 1)
      lvBasket(i - 1) = DirectCast(ctl(0), ListView)
      ctl = Me.Controls.Find("btnSave" & i.ToString, True)
      ReDim Preserve btnSave(i - 1)
      btnSave(i - 1) = DirectCast(ctl(0), Button)
      i += 1
    Loop

    For i = 0 To lvBasket.GetUpperBound(0)
      AddHandler lvBasket(i).MouseDoubleClick, AddressOf lvBasket_MouseDoubleClick
      AddHandler btnSave(i).Click, AddressOf btnSave_Click
    Next
  End Sub

  Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MsgBox(DirectCast(sender, Button).Name)
  End Sub

  Private Sub lvBasket_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    MsgBox(DirectCast(sender, ListView).Name)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Yes Me.Controls.Find("lvBasket" & i, True) worked fine. True parameter really does the trick because it is searching child controls as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I've implemented a solution. My actual controls are named without underscore, like lvBasket1.

```
Imports System.Linq.Expressions

Private _txtNameSurname(BasketCount), _txtPhone(BasketCount) As TextBox
Private _btnSelectCustomer(BasketCount), _btnAddProduct(BasketCount) As Button
Private _lblInfo(BasketCount) As Label
Private _lvBasket(BasketCount) As ListView

Private Sub AssignControl(Of ControlType)(index As Integer, controlArrayFunc As_
        Expression(Of Func(Of ControlType())))

    Dim controlArray = controlArrayFunc.Compile()()
    Dim keyword = CType(controlArrayFunc.Body, MemberExpression).Member.Name.TrimStart("_"c)

    controlArray(index) =_
        Me.Controls.Find(keyword & (index + 1), True).OfType(Of ControlType).Single()
End Sub

Private Sub InitControlsArrayAndEventHandlers()
    For i As Integer = 0 To BasketCount
        AssignControl(i, Function() _lvBasket)

        AssignControl(i, Function() _txtNameSurname)
        AssignControl(i, Function() _txtPhone)

        AssignControl(i, Function() _btnSelectCustomer)
        AssignControl(i, Function() _btnAddProduct)

        AssignControl(i, Function() _lblInfo)

        AddHandler _lvBasket(i).MouseDoubleClick, AddressOf vlBasket_Click

        AddHandler _btnSelectCustomer(i).Click, AddressOf btnSelectCustomer_Click
    Next
End Sub
```